# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://

Tags: java, ioexception

I am getting the below mentioned error while trying to invoke a servlet in IBM websphere.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: 
   https://<URL>
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1196)
   at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.a.getInputStream(a.java:3)
   at com.infy.finacle.finreport.extscheduler.RIExecuteExternalJob.main(RIExecuteExternalJob.java:89)
```

Kindly help me with debugging the issue.

Comment: You need to look at the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP code 500 is a server-side error and in general you should try browsing to the URL with your browser first to see if it is a genuine server error.

However, in this case it looks like you have passed an incomplete URL `https://`.

Comment: i have passed the complete url. Due to business reasons we cannot share the url. sorry for that. for  some of the request its working fine . for some its failing with the failure message as shown above.

Comment: It sounds like a server error especially given its intermittent - do you have access to the web server to check its logs? If not, you should ask the provider to assist.

Comment: i have the access to web server.

Comment: Please hit the url in the browser and find out if its giving some thing to you. if its giving any error like "405 method not allowed" in browser that means that url you are trying is not exposed or secured.

Comment: Also check your if you are using text instead of . This was the reason for my issues and i changed to XML. XMLhttpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml");